# Positive roots and the longest element of the Weyl group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Take $\frak{g}$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra and its Weyl group $W$. Is it true that the number of positive roots of $\frak{g}$ is equal to the length of the longest element of $W$?

Comment: Yes it is true..

Comment: Bourbaki, *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, ch. VI, §1, Cor. 3 of Prop. 17.